VS Code manual folding ranges disappear upon opening a file on another machine
Since I work on my laptop at my workplace and then usually continue home on my desktop PC, I would like to have my VS Code manual folding ranges persist between machines. Upon opening any file on a PC, the manual folding ranges created on the laptop are gone.
Struggling to figure out how to fix this. 
Maybe they are mapped to some external file? No idea, honestly.
Is this just my problem? Would like to hear from others.
Tried searching the web. Monitored it for months since manual folding ranges were added. Never got any search hits. Browsed GitHub repo for a bit, also got nothing.
